# Can I use the Sort method on an Integer Array?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an Integer array (`int[] myArray`) in my ASP.NET webpage.
I am trying to use the `Array.Sort()` function, but the `Sort()` method is not available. It's only available when I use `ArrayList`. Am I missing a namespace?

Example of what I have:

```
int[] intArray = new int[7, 4, 8, 0, 2, 10, 3];
intArray.Sort();   // gets an error
```

My error says:

> No overload for method 'sort' takes '0' arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the static method in the Array class:

```
Array.Sort(intArray)
```

Answer (score 4):

That's not the best possible error message. You have to pass `intArray` to the `Sort` method, but you're doing so already. The actual problem is that [`Array.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwx6zbd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a static method, not an instance method, so it should be called as `Array.Sort(intArray);`.

Comment: Thank you @hvd that did the job. Much appreciated.